# VS2017 change netstandard project version via msbuild

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, there is a new format for netstandard libraries that makes generating nupkg reasonably straight-forward. It looks like this:

[image]

In the csproj, it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way of telling msbuild what the package version should be in such away that projects across the sln are updated simultaneously so that the nuspec ends up having the right version dependency? It is probably bug, but when I use `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:PackageVersion=3.1.7` and the original hand-typed version is 2.0.0. If I have an alpha and beta project, with beta dependent on alpha, I'll end up with

> alpha-3.1.7.nupkg
>
> beta-3.1.7.nupkg dependent on alpha-2.0.0

Perhaps the only way is regex substitution on the csproj, but it would be nice if I could avoid that.

Also, this PackageVersion method does not update the real version:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the versions are locked during restore and not during the build.

As a workaround, you can use

```
msbuild /restore /p:Version=1.2.3
```

(Recommended, requires MSBuild 15.5+)

or

```
msbuild /t:Restore;Pack /p:Version=1.2.3
```

(`Version` will also affect the generated assembly version, but you can use `PackageVersion` to only change the generated nupkg version).

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4337) for tracking the underlying NuGet issue (currently, the plan is that the dependency versions will be updated during the build in a future release).

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean that I msbuild /t:restore and then msbuild /t:build?

Comment: you can do it in one invocation in this case if you want. (`/t:Restore;Build` or using a `,` to separate the targets). The point is that restore and build/pack need to be passed the same parameters

Comment: MSBuild 15.5 has a `/restore` parameter that works perfectly for this (performs a `Restore` target, flushes all caches and then performs a build)

Comment: If you use e.g. `dotnet pack /p:Version=1.2.3`, this is already done this way. Only if you use msbuild directly, you need to care about restore.

Comment: I just tried this although I had to keep my old 'nuget restore', then 'msbuild /t:restore /p:Version=x.x.x' then a visual studio 2017 build. It did work, though it feels rather shaky. Thanks for the help, I had been working on this for the past few hrs.

Comment: do you happen to know how i pass nuget servers to msbuild? maybe i don't need the old nuget restore

Comment: it still reads nuget.config but you can also use `RestoreSources` (semicolon-separated url list). If you do a full restore, do use the `/restore` argument and not `/t:Restore;Build`!

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-NuGet-settings-in-MSBuild

Comment: The fix in NuGet has been made ([this pull request](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/1915)) and will be included in NuGet 4.6.0 (=> VS 15.6)