# msbuild pack specify version?

Tags: windows, msbuild, nuget

This is what I do with nuget pack now:

```
nuget.exe pack myapp.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Properties Configuration=Release;prerelease=INeedToSetThisFromTheCommandNotStaticConfigFile-123
```

msbuild pack says no

```
msbuild myapp.csproj /T:pack /p:Configuration=Release;prerelease="-INeedToSetThisFromTheCommandNotStaticConfigFile-123"
```

> prerelease=-INeedToSetThisFromTheCommandNotStaticConfigFile-123 : The
>   term 'prerelease=-INeedToSetThisFromTheCommandNotStaticConfigFile-123'
>   is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2017 change netstandard project version via msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056724/vs2017-change-netstandard-project-version-via-msbuild)

Answer (score 0):

In you `.csproj` file, set the tag `Version` to be `$(TheVersion)`, and set this parameter from the command line.

`Configuration=Release;TheVersion=123`